# loop random line file text in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, random, while-loop

I'm trying to complete my code.

file text ex codetest.txt:

```
aaaa
eeeee
rrrrrrr
tttt
yyyyyy
uuuuu
iiiiiii
ooooo
ppppppppp
llllllll
```

I want a code that takes a random line in a text file and then prints it to the screen, deleting the printed line in the text file. I have finished my code.
It worked:

```
import random
import sys
f = open("codetest.txt", "r")
lines = f.read().splitlines()
random_lines = random.sample(lines, 1)
code = "\n".join(random_lines)  # var code
w = open("codetest.txt", "w")
w.writelines(line + "\n" for line in lines if line not in random_lines)
print("code :", code)
```

Now I want a loop that will perform repeated work on until in the empty text file. it not worked
my code loop:

```
import random
import sys
i=0
while i<5:

    i+=1
    f = open("codetest.txt", "r")
    lines = f.read().splitlines()
    random_lines = random.sample(lines, 1)
    code = "\n".join(random_lines)  # var code
    w = open("codetest.txt", "w")
    w.writelines(line + "\n" for line in lines if line not in random_lines)
    print("code",i," : ", code)
```

Comment: Please tell me in detail.
I'm new pythoner
thank you

Comment: not `while 1<2:` . it will be `while i<2:`.

Comment: while i<2:

erro:C:\python3.6\python.exe E:/Python/ex/test/test.py
code 1  :  yyyyyy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/Python/ex/test/test.py", line 36, in <module>
    random_lines = random.sample(lines, 1)
  File "C:\python3.6\lib\random.py", line 317, in sample
    raise ValueError("Sample larger than population or is negative")
ValueError: Sample larger than population or is negative

Comment: I think the problem is that you're not closing the file. Before writing use: f.close() and also before leaving loop use w.close(). Also please use the "with open(...) as f:" statement. Then you don't have to think about closing the file as it closes automatically after use.

Comment: thanks. That is my shortcoming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little quirk in python: if you do not close a file,  **it will never write any data to it**. 
(your first program worked only because python closed the file automatically when the program ended.)

Try adding `w.close()` as the final line of your loop.

It is good practice to close file when you are done using them. Hope this helps :)

Comment: Tuyệt vời, nó đã làm việc. cảm ơn.That is my shortcoming.

Answer (score 0):

It's missing `.close()`

Example:

```
w = open("codetest.txt", "w")
w.writelines( ...stuffs... )
w.close()
```

Without `.close()`, the written lines will be buffered in memory. For first situation, the file will be automatically closed when exiting program. But in the latter situation, `f` and `w` are not closed properly.

Better style can be like this:

```
with open("codetest.txt", "w") as w:
    w.writelines( ...stuffs... )
```

The `with` statement will deal with the life cycle of file objects.
https://docs.python.org/3.5/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement

Answer (score 0):

I wanted the file io practice, used the recommended `with open():` idiom

and saw that `list.pop(index)` fits the code spec by doing 2 needed operations at once

`print("code :", lines.pop(random.randrange(len(lines))))` does almost all the non file io work

```
import random
import sys

txt = """aaaa
eeeee
rrrrrrr
tttt
yyyyyy
uuuuu
iiiiiii
ooooo
ppppppppp
llllllll
"""
with open('codetest.txt', 'w+') as f:
    f.writelines(txt)

while True:
    with open('codetest.txt', 'r') as f:
        lines = f.read().splitlines()
    if lines:  # check if file is (not)empty
        print("code :", lines.pop(random.randrange(len(lines))))
        with open('codetest.txt', 'w') as f:
            f.writelines(s+'\n' for s in lines)
    else:
        break  # file is empty, break out of while loop

code : aaaa
code : tttt
code : ooooo
code : ppppppppp
code : iiiiiii
code : yyyyyy
code : llllllll
code : rrrrrrr
code : uuuuu
code : eeeee
```